# How to design terms of conditions and Agreements screen like gmail in android webview

Tags: android-layout

I have terms of conditions and Agreements screen in android webview I want to design that screen like gmail, in which we will have down arrow if we click on that it will scroll down automatically. How can I implement the same.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Actually I have no idea how to do this. I searched for the procedure to do the same but I didn't find any solution.

Comment: Please see [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) and related examples. if still you got issue, updated here.